# File readable & writable only by server php and not from client

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have some txt files with informations, but this ***.txt** files is going to be readable and writable by server php, (for example include them or just check them).

but i dont what this files to be accesstable from browser for example the user must can not 
view the files with http:// mysite/myfile.txt

what perrmission i have to set up for this files when php makes them?

Comment: You can setup an .htaccess file to deny acccess to the file, or you can store the file outside your website's root.

Comment: for example what i have to make to the .htaccess ?

Comment: @user2773673 Read my answer.

Comment: Don't mess with permissions. Put the files outside your document root and they'll be invisible/inaccessible to everyone except your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using permissions. In both cases server will read file.

You have to put this file in public parent directory (eg. in directory where is your `public_html`). This way you'll be still able to include it but noone can read it using browser.

Second option is to set correct `.htaccess` file to deny all users (it'll still allow you to read it from scripts), eg. like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```